# How to store multidimensional array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have below array

```
[
  Sheet1: [
    headers: [
      'First Name New',
      'Last Name',
      'Gender',
      'Country',
      'Age',
      'Date',
      'Id'
    ],
    data_count: 10
  ],
  Sheet2: [
    headers: [
      'First Name New',
      'Last Name',
      'Gender',
      'Country',
      'Age',
      'Date',
      'Id'
    ],
    data_count: 10
  ]
]
```

I want to store it in mongodb. But it didn't get stored. An empty array is getting stored

Comment: What language are you using here?   The example above is not an array of arrays; it is an array of objects (key/value) where some of the objects are lists of scalars.   Please edit your example to reflect something that works in javascript or python or java.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I am using nestjs a nodejs frmaework

Comment: @whoami I want how this data an be stored in mongodb

Comment: Do you want Sheet1 and Sheet2 to be together in a single doc in mongodb?   Or is Sheet1 a separate  "record" from Sheet2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB document you can store two types of *composite fields*: (1) arrays and (2) documents (sometimes referred as embedded or sub-documents). Arrays can embed other arrays and/or sub-documents, *and* sub-documents can embed arrays and/or sub-documents within them.

For ***example***, the following document has all the fields as array type (except the `_id`):

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "arr_of_numbers" : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                100
        ],
        "arr_of_documents" : [
                {
                        "name" : "John",
                        "country" : "USA"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Krishna",
                        "country" : "India"
                }
        ],
        "arr_of_arrays" : [
                [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3
                ],
                [
                        11,
                        21
                ]
        ],
        "arr_of_documents_with_arrays" : [
                {
                        "fld1" : "string-1",
                        "fld2" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "John",
                                        "country" : "USA"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "Krishna",
                                        "country" : "India"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "fld1" : "string-2",
                        "fld2" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "Ivan",
                                        "country" : "Bulgaria"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "Vladi",
                                        "country" : "Russia"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Consider ***your array***:

```
[
  Sheet1: [
    headers: [
      'First Name New',
      'Last Name',
      'Gender',
      'Country',
      'Age',
      'Date',
      'Id'
    ],
    data_count: 10
  ],
  Sheet2: [
    headers: [
      'First Name New',
      'Last Name',
      'Gender',
      'Country',
      'Age',
      'Date',
      'Id'
    ],
    data_count: 10
  ]
]
```

*Your array cannot be stored as it is*. As my example shows, that an array with sub-documents is what you have to consider. So, your document can have something like the following:

```
{
   "_id":1,
   "some_field":"some value",
   "my_multi_array":[
      {
         "Sheet1":{
            "headers":[
               "First Name New",
               "Last Name",
               "Gender",
               "Country",
               "Age",
               "Date",
               "Id"
            ],
            "data_count":10
         }
      },
      {
         "Sheet2":{
            "headers":[
               "First Name New",
               "Last Name",
               "Gender",
               "Country",
               "Age",
               "Date",
               "Id"
            ],
            "data_count":10
         }
      }
   ]
}
```